# A large discrepancy evaluating $\int_{5.566}^{5.568}\frac{(\sin 6x)^{14}}{(\cos 11x)^{8}}dx$ with Hiper Scientific Calculator vs WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, calculator

So, in a nutshell, dealing with *Hiper Scientific Calculator* and *Wolframalpha Integral Calculator* . Only this integral

$$\int_{5.566}^{5.568}\frac{(\sin 6x)^{14}}{(\cos 11x)^{8}}dx$$

is being strangely computed by the respective calculators $28,066,763,000$ for hiper and $5.61409 \times 10^{10}$ for WA. What could've gone wrong? Why is that happening anyway ?

Kindly look into the attached screenshots for the specifics. Hoping to find a way out of this.

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j642p.jpg)

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPV8D.jpg)

Comment: You're close to a zero of $\cos(11x)$, so some numerical methods will make large approximation errors. I get the same result in Mathematica that you got in WolframAlpha, and I trust Wolfram more than Hiper (which I've never heard of).

Comment: Because the integrand is very very big due to a very very small denominator in the vicinity of $5.569187... = \pi \times \frac{39}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

There is an explicit antiderivative and then we have the exact value of the  definite integral.

To explain the huge numbers : there is a denominator

$$(2 \cos (2 x)-2 \cos (4 x)+2 \cos (6 x)-2 \cos (8 x)+2 \cos (10
   x)-1)^7$$

Using $\cos(2t)=x$
$$32 t^5-16 t^4-32 t^3+12 t^2+6 t-1$$ shows five real roots and one of them corresponds to $x=5.5691869768182698318\cdots$

So, at the lower bound, the denominator is $-4.70495\times 10^{-10}$ and $-4.6264\times 10^{-13}$ at the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you set HiperCalc to radians, you will get (almost) the same answer as Wolfram Alpha (I got $5.6134 \cdot 10^{10}$, which is an error of about $1.3\%$).  Numerical methods will get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

Maple agrees with Wolfram Alpha.  Using 100 digits of precision, both numerical integration and the (rather unpleasant) closed-form formula give results of approximately
$$ 5.614093676901550871856281466889638286126491248415545\times 10^{10}$$